# How to Post both Files and Other Types of Input in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I am learning PHP and wish to deal with database.

Basically, I want the users to be able to put in some string in input1 and upload the file as well. Then, after the form has been submitted, I want to store the value of input1 and the path of the file in a database. In w3school, I have encountered a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) on how to upload a file. However, the tutorial does not deal when I am trying to upload a file and an input at the same time. Below is the code that I have so far.

So how do I go about doing it? Thanks!

```
<form id="form" action="uploaded.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <pre>
          input1: <input type="text" name="in1" maxlength="20">
                      File: <input type="file" name="uploadThis">

     </pre>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Open ^ your link again and compare your form header tag with the one in w3c, you will see you're missing an important attribute.

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks! But do you know how to go about passing the file and the input?

Comment: So now your problem is how to save the file and then save the path to the db?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yea. Is it that the input will be post as $_POST['input1'] and the file as $_FILE['uploadThis']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to type out exactly how to, because I'm on my iPad, but you'll need to make an `if(isset($_POST['sumbit']))` statement for the submit, watch some tutorials on if statements, preferably by PHPacademy. You'll also need something to insert data with, `INSERT INTO your db info goes here SELECT your db info goes here FROM your db info goes here`. You can find information on doing that with YouTube or Google. You should also add a form action to your `<form>` , ex. `<form action='#'>`.